# Git `git ls-files -m` Not Showing New Files

Tags: git, macos

When I run `git ls-files -m`, new files are not shown (whether staged or not). Modified files are shown.

This is:

1. Different behavior than my colleagues get. They see new files too
2. Persistent even if I upgrade my git version (just upgraded to 2.13.2)

**What might be causing this behavior?**

I've tried on a new repository and removing my `~/.gitconfig`: none of this helped.

**I also tried a completely new Mac user (and a new repo) and, surprisingly, this same behavior persisted.**

Comment: Your colleagues are having you on.

Comment: @jthill or probably some confusion in communication. The whole point was to get a `git whiteout` command -- which runs through files using `git ls-files -m` -- to include new files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git ls-files -m` isn't supposed to show new files. A new file may appear in the output of `git ls-files -m` only if it is modified after being staged:

```
$ git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test/.git/
$ cd test/
$ git ls-files -m
$ touch newfile
$ git ls-files -m
$ git add newfile 
$ git ls-files -m
$ echo sometext >> newfile
$ git ls-files -m
newfile                        # <----
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains the confusion. You have to add the file and **then** modify it. Great.